# Please explain the behavior of this Parsec permutation parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Why does this [Parsec permutation parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Perm.html) not parse **b**?

```
p :: Parser (String, String)
p = permute (pair
              <$?> ("", pa)
              <|?> ("", pb))
  where pair a b = (a, b)

pa :: Parser String
pa = do
  char 'x'
  many1 (char 'a')

pb :: Parser String
pb = do
  many1 (char 'b')

λ> parseTest p "xaabb"
("aa","bb")               -- expected result, good
λ> parseTest p "aabb"
("","")                   -- why "" for b?
```

Parser `pa` is configured as optional via `<$?>` so I don't understand why its failing has impacted the parsing of **b**. I can change it to `optional (char 'x')` to get the expected behavior, but I don't understand why.

```
pa :: Parser String
pa = do
  optional (char 'x')
  many1 (char 'a')

pb :: Parser String
pb = do
  optional (char 'x')
  many1 (char 'b')

λ> parseTest p "xaaxbb"
parse error at (line 1, column 2):
unexpected "a"
expecting "b"
λ> parseTest p "xbbxaa"
("aa","bb")
```

How can both input orderings be supported when we have identical shared prefix "x"?

I also don't understand the impact that consumption of the optional "x" is having on the parse behavior:

```
pb :: Parser String
pb = do
  try px -- with this try x remains unconsumed and "aa" gets parsed
         -- without this try x is consumed, but "aa" isn't parsed even though "x" is optional anyway
  many1 (char 'b')

px :: Parser Char
px = do
  optional (char 'x')
  char 'x' <?> "second x"

λ> parseTest p "xaaxbb"            -- without try on px
parse error at (line 1, column 2):
unexpected "a"
expecting second x
λ> parseTest p "xaaxbb"            -- with try on px
("aa","")
```

Comment: Because once `pa` fails, the whole string `"aabb"` is passed to `pb`, not just the `"bb"` part

Comment: Thanks Alec, that makes sense. I've added a related question in case you would be able to explain. Feel free to answer below so I could accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why `parseTest p "aabb"` gives `("","")`

The permutation parser tries to strip off the front of the given string prefixes that can be parsed by its constituent parsers (`pa` and `pb` in this case). Here, it will have tried to apply both `pa` and `pb` to `"aabb"` and failed in both cases - it never even gets around to trying to parse `"bb"`.

#### Why can't both `pa` and `pb` start with `optional (char 'x')`

Looking at [`permute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Perm.html#permute), you'll see it uses [`choice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Combinator.html#choice), which in turn relies on [`(<|>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:-60--124--62-). As the documentation of `(<|>)` says,

> This combinator implements choice. The parser `p <|> q` first applies `p`. If it succeeds, the value of `p` is returned. If `p` fails without consuming any input, parser `q` is tried. This combinator is defined equal to the `mplus` member of the `MonadPlus` class and the `(<|>)` member of `Alternative`.
>
> The parser is called predictive since `q` is only tried when parser `p` didn't consume any input (i.e.. the look ahead is 1). This non-backtracking behaviour allows for both an efficient implementation of the parser combinators and the generation of good error messages.

So when you do something like `parseTest p "xbb"`, `pa` doesn't fail immediately (it consumes and `'x'`) and then the whole thing fails because it cannot backtrack.

### How to make shared prefixes work?

As Daniel has suggested, it is best to factor out your grammar. Alternately, you can use `try`:

> The parser `try p` behaves like parser `p`, except that it pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs

Based on what we talked about before for `(<|>)`, you ought then to put `try` in front of both of `optional (char 'x')`.

Comment: Thanks Alec! This makes perfect sense now. One minor note: putting `try` in front of both `optional (char 'x'))` doesn't actually get it working because the "x" is always successfully consumed; the `try` won't change a successful consumption to empty. What I needed was all of `pa` and `pb` to fail as a single unit so I wrapped both the `optional` and `many1` in a single `try` so when the `many1` fails it returns empty for the whole thing, not having consumed even the "x" successfully, and is now able to try the alternate parser.

Comment: I just saw Daniel's comment where he explains that the try needs to wrap the entire thing. Great to see I was on the right track! I understand why now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this Parsec permutation parser not parse b?

Because `'a'` is not a valid first character for either parser `pa` or parser `pb`.

> How can both input orderings be supported when we have identical shared prefix "x"?

Shared prefixes must be factored out of your grammar; or backtracking points inserted (using `try`) at the cost of performance.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What I still don't understand is why the sequence of either the parsers in the `permute` setup or the input matter. I thought the point was that both "pa then pb" and "pb then pa" would be tried, but it appears from my second example above that sequence does matter. Manually reordering pa and pb in permute will switch the success and failure modes. Furthermore, adding tries to the optional xs doesn't impact the result; it doesn't seem to matter if they are consumed or not as they are optional.

Comment: I don't understand why the input isn't passed on to `pa` once `pb` fails, regardless of whether or not the "x" has been consumed. Instead it just reports the failure of `pb` to parse and that's it.

Comment: The order matters because both parsers start with a common prefix, and in parsec, `p1 <|> p2` is not in general the same as `p2 <|> p1`. In your case, once the `x` has been recognized, parsec commits to one order. You have to use `try` or left-factor the `x` out if you want to avoid that.

Comment: @rcampbell Lots to discuss here. First: it is not true that both "`pa` then `pb`" and "`pb` then `pa`" will be tried; if the first of the two that is tried consumes any input at all, the other will not be tried at all. Second: the `try` will need to wrap the *entire* thing that needs to be backed out -- so not `try (optional ...)` but `try pa`. Note how this meshes with the first point: `try p` only consumes input if `p` succeeds. Third: hopefully the above discussion addresses your second comment; input isn't passed on to `pa` once `pb` fails because `pb` consumed some input before it failed.